# Sound when button switch scene

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, audio, c#-2.0, scene2d

What I am trying to do is when I press the button, it makes a sound and switch scene but it is delay 2s or 3s when i press the button and then it makes a sound so when i press a button it switches scene but doesn't make a sound ma code is:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class mainManuControler : MonoBehaviour {
    
     public AudioSource src;
    
     public AudioClip srcOne;

     public void PlayGame() {

        src.clip = srcOne;

        src.Play();

        SceneManager.LoadScene("Game");
    }
}
```

How i can get rid of delay in audio.

Comment: Are you using bluetooth headset ?

Comment: No I am not....

Answer (score 2):

It might be because you play the sound and immediately change scene. You can wait for the sound to finish playing then load that scene. See if this works:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
    
public class mainManuControler : MonoBehaviour
{

    public AudioSource src;
    public AudioClip srcOne;

    public void PlayGame()
    {
        src.PlayOneShot(srcOne);
        StartCoroutine(_PlayGame());
    }

    private IEnumerator _PlayGame()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(srcOne.length);
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Game");
    }
}
```